# How to check if a pull request is merged in some branch of the target repository?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

Excuse me but this may be a noob question but it jsut crossed my thoughts and I think it is worth to fix my ideas and get a relevant explanation from some experts.

I remember (I may be wrong) that when I submitted some pull requests to some repository, when the PR is merged to the master (or other branch), I'm notified about that action and when accessing the PR url I can see a sort of **This PR has been merged into...** message.

Just browsing an old issue, I can no more see that kinf of message and what is only seen is that the issue is closed:

[image]

No merge message and I had to go through the blame to check file history and find whether my PR was merged.

If I'm walking the wrong road, can anyone clarify my thoughts and correct me I I'm wrong?
If I'm not supposed to see such a merge message in the PR page, so how can I check if a PR is merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Your PR hasn't been merged.

Its content has been manually merged by **[anhvurz90](https://github.com/anhvurz90)** because of conflicts in `core/services/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/services/cms/impl/Utils.java` (as one can see in the messages of the merged commits).

**Details**

- Your **[PR](https://github.com/exoplatform/ecms/pull/603)** contains commits **[eff1cd9](https://github.com/exoplatform/ecms/commit/eff1cd9)** and **[6acb5f2](https://github.com/exoplatform/ecms/commit/6acb5f2)**.
- The main repository contains the commits **[0263ead](https://github.com/exoplatform/ecms/commit/0263ead)** and **[07dfb20](https://github.com/exoplatform/ecms/commit/07dfb20)**.

> If I'm walking the wrong road, can anyone clarify my thoughts and correct me I I'm wrong? If I'm not supposed to see such a merge message in the PR page, so how can I check if a PR is merged?

Usually, when a PR cannot cleanly get merged, the contributor is asked to rebase it and solve the conflicts. However, from time to time, the core team may decide to merge it by hand if the conflicts are easy enough to fix.

In that case, you're right that a *"Manually merged! Thanks for the code!"* may give the contributor some hint about what happened.

> How to check if a pull request is merged in some branch of the target repository?

In that kind of cases, you may take a look at the commits in the master branch that you've authored:

- https://github.com/exoplatform/ecms/commits/master?author=tmarwen

Comment: So if my thoughts are right, in such cases where conflicts may occur and the merge in not directelly done from PR, then I have to look out for the matching commits in the master with messages from my PR to find the respective commits.
But if my PR have not been merged, how could it be that I'm an author of a commit in that branch then?
Please could you clarify that?

Comment: The core contributor fetched your commits from your branch, merged them locally on his/her computer then pushed to the main repository the result.